# How i will find and edit this get_template_part( 'content/post-byline' ); wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to find this line in word press and want to change it contents and update it according to my need, how will i find this function in word press.

```
get_template_part( 'content/post-byline' );
```

how will i find where is post-byline function written, 
i want to extent and change this line.
" Published May 14, 2018 by Admin "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_template_part( 'content/post-byline' ) function is actually looking for a file name   post-byline.php and which reside in the content folder.
So go to the content folder inside your theme and find "post-byline.php" file.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to read more from WordPress codex page. There is too many user contribution with examples about `get_template_part()` function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/